# Kafka docker image that works without zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka

I read that Kafka no longer requires zookeeper, so I don't want to have zookeeper in docker-compose. But I don't know which kafka image can work w/o zookeeper. can anyone give a hint?

Comment: You could use a container that includes both, like fast-data-dev, but that creates a single point of failure

Comment: The recently released Apache Kafka 2.8 supports a preview mode for KRaft mode which is where it doesn't use Zookeeper: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.8/config/kraft/README.md

Comment: It is in early access phase (still as of Jan 2022).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I read that Kafka no longer requires zookeeper

You may well have read that *in the future* Apache Kafka will not need Zookeeper - this is detailed in [KIP-500](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-500%3A+Replace+ZooKeeper+with+a+Self-Managed+Metadata+Quorum)

However, this is not yet implemented, so for the time being (January 2021) you will still need a Zookeeper in your Docker Compose ensemble.

Comment: In April 2021, can we use the Kafka 2.8.0 with KIP-500 preview for docker-compose dev environments for dev/testing basic Kafka workflows?

Comment: I am also looking for the same thing. Is there an actual example for Kafka 2.8.0 using `docker-compose`?

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/tree/6.2.0-post/cp-all-in-one-kraft

Comment: do we have an official kafka docker image out now? without zookeeper?

Answer (score 15):

Here's a Kafka Docker image which doesn't required Zookeeper (as described above):

https://hub.docker.com/r/bashj79/kafka-kraft

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Comment: Link to source of ⬆️, please?  

Comment: Here's the source code in GitHub. Feel free to contribute any improvements :)

https://github.com/bashj79/kafka-kraft-docker

Comment: You may post a working docker-compose.yaml as help to get it running. I can't get it up and running due to the broker seems not to fine the controller (which is the broker itself). *Log:* `INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=1 name=heartbeat]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker localhost:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)`
`WARN [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=1 name=heartbeat] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)`

Answer (score 12):

According to "What’s New in **Apache Kafka 3.3**" document and "**KIP-833**: Mark KRaft as Production Ready" Kafka can work without Zookeeper (but there are some features yet works only by Apache ZooKeeper (ZK) mode).

Example (*docker-compose.yml*):

```yaml
version: "2.5"
volumes:
  volume1:
services:
  kafka1:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:3.3.1'
    container_name: kafka
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=broker,controller
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@kafka1:9093
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID=r4zt_wrqTRuT7W2NJsB_GA
    volumes:
      - volume1:/bitnami/kafka
  kafka-ui:
    container_name: kafka-ui
    image: 'provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest'
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka1:9092
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=r4zt_wrqTRuT7W2NJsB_GA
```

You could try localhost:8080 and you will see that it works perfectly.

Comment: I couldn't connect to this from spring boot application. my connection string is: spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092. I need to connect from "localhost". Its giving this error: *********[Consumer clientId=consumer-group-id-1, groupId=group-id] Error connecting to node kafka:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)
java.net.UnknownHostException: kafka

Comment: I think it's matter of Docker network and Kafka listeners configuration: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/, the goal of above docker-compose file is just to demonstrate Kafka can work without Zookeeper.

Comment: Works, tested with image `bitnami/kafka:3.3.2`. I had to add the env variable `KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=1`

Comment: when I try to create a producer for Kafka messages I get error `NoBrokersAvailable`

Comment: I do not get why you specified volumes without anything in it ?  Also thx to @MarcusSchiesser I could run it  :).  So besides the CFG also volumes can be deleted :)  and it worked. Anyway thx for the solution daniil

Comment: I did not manage to see in the ui schema registry to configure messages. Is there also something more that needs to  be added ?

Comment: A keey missing of this answer is docker network specification.

Answer (score 8):

Confluent published a working *docker-compose.yaml* without zookeeper in their repository [cp-all-in-one](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/tree/master/cp-all-in-one-kraft).

There is a script (*update_run.sh*) used as a workaround

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Docker workaround: Remove check for KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT parameter
sed -i '/KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT/d' /etc/confluent/docker/configure

# Docker workaround: Ignore cub zk-ready
sed -i 's/cub zk-ready/echo ignore zk-ready/' /etc/confluent/docker/ensure

# KRaft required step: Format the storage directory with a new cluster ID
echo "kafka-storage format --ignore-formatted -t $(kafka-storage random-uuid) -c /etc/kafka/kafka.properties" >> /etc/confluent/docker/ensure
```

which is called in the *command* of the docker-compose-setup

```yaml
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.2.x-latest
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@broker:29093'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,CONTROLLER://broker:29093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'
    volumes:
      - ./update_run.sh:/tmp/update_run.sh
    command: "bash -c 'if [ ! -f /tmp/update_run.sh ]; then echo \"ERROR: Did you forget the update_run.sh file that came with this docker-compose.yml file?\" && exit 1 ; else /tmp/update_run.sh && /etc/confluent/docker/run ; fi'"
```

Comment: Don't forget the data volume for persistence: `- kafka:/var/lib/kafka/data`

Answer (score 7):

You can use this image for no Zookeeper.

https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka

Here is a example yaml.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:3.2.3'
    restart: "no"
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 19092:19092
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=broker,controller
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:19092,CONTROLLER://:2181
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:19092
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@127.0.0.1:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
```

Comment: This is not a correct answer to this question. The docs on the link you shared specifically call out to launch a zookeeper instance in order to connect to this Kafka instance, and furthermore the sample docker-compose on that page also contains an instance of zookeeper. This question is asking for the Kafka version that uses the Raft algorithm (essentially a distributed consensus algorithm) to manage instances.

Answer (score 6):

So far the easiest way is to use [confluent-local](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/confluent-local) image. It uses default environment variables defined [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/blob/7.4.x/local/include/etc/confluent/docker/configureDefaults).

```yml
---
version: '2'
services:
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/confluent-local:7.4.1
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
```

Or if you need to use [kafka-ui](https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui), you should also configure some env variables (for [listeners](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/) etc):

```yml
---
version: '2'
services:

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/confluent-local:7.4.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@broker:29093'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,CONTROLLER://broker:29093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092'

  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - 9999:8080
    environment:
      DYNAMIC_CONFIG_ENABLED: true
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: broker:29092
```

Answer (score 4):

Confluent released a slimmed down [confluent-local](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/confluent-local) image in June 2023 that can run Kafka without ZooKeeper and can be used with Docker Compose.

If you just need Kafka, you can use the Confluent CLI instead of Docker Compose to manage the `confluent-local` container. One-liner from [this](https://developer.confluent.io/quickstart/kafka-local/) quick start to get going: `brew install confluentinc/tap/cli && confluent local kafka start`

Disclaimer: I'm a Confluent employee

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [@daniil_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6160271/daniil)'s post.

This cluster setup works for me.

```
version: "3"
volumes:
  broker1:
  broker2:
services:
  broker1:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    container_name: broker1
    environment:
      KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT: yes
      KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker1:9092
      KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@broker1:9093,2@broker2:9093'
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
      KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID: r4zt_wrqTRuT7W2NJsB_GA
    volumes:
      - broker1:/bitnami/kafka
  broker2:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    container_name: broker2
    environment:
      KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT: yes
      KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker2:9092
      KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@broker1:9093,2@broker2:9093'
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
      KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID: r4zt_wrqTRuT7W2NJsB_GA
    volumes:
      - broker2:/bitnami/kafka
  kafka-ui:
    container_name: kafka-ui
    image: 'provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest'
    depends_on:
      - broker1
      - broker2
    ports:
      - "8092:8080"
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker1:9092,broker2:9092'
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local-kafka-cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as of Semptember 2023:

```
kafka:
  restart: always
  image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.3
  volumes:
    - ./.volumes/kafka/data:/bitnami"
  ports:
    - 9092:9092
    - 9093:9093
  container_name: broker1
  environment:
    KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT: yes
    KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID: 1
    KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
    KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
    KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
    KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
    KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
    KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker1:9092
    KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID: 1
    KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@broker1:9093'
    ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
    KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID: r4zt_wrqTRuT7W2NJsB_GA
```